# Programas e/ou extensão que "descompilem" DLLs de um site ASP

Tags: asp.net, compilação, dll

Alguém sabe de algum programa ou extensão que possa fazer uma espécie de "descompilamento" de arquivos DLL  (que contém classes de um site) em arquivos CS e ASPX.CS?

Por enquanto, só sei do .NET Reflector, que é usado como extensão do Visual Studio. Ele consegue acesso aos CS, mas não consegui acessar os códigos de arquivos ASPX.CS, por enquanto.

Preciso disso pra poder acessar todas as fontes de um site feito em ASP.NET com C#, que assumi de outro desenvolvedor (que entrei em contato pra que me passe esses fontes atualizados, mas por enquanto não recebi retorno dele. Por isso estou indo por vários caminhos). E isso inclui os ASPX.CS

O que posso fazer?

Comment: Tente o ILSpy: http://ilspy.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso o ILSpy, ele é muito bom e até hoje não tive problemas com ele:

http://ilspy.net/

Comment: Achei muito bom, instalei no próprio Visual Studio. Porém, apesar de eu ver o código C# que tem nos DLLs, eu não consigo editar esse código. O que eu posso fazer nesse caso?